# ASP.NET MVC Core How Can I show the Route Value in Ienumerable View Page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, ienumerable, viewdata

I have a simple route...[controller]/{region} in my Index Controller.

So in the url you would see.. http://localhost:51588/Movies/malta
(where 'malta' is the region)

And in the code for the subsequent index.cshtml view  which list the movies of 'malta' view I have..

```
@model IEnumerable<MaltaMoviesMVCcore.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Movies";
}
```

Q...I would like to add the 'region' dynamically to the  above ["Title"] so it shows as 'Locations - Malta'
I've tried.... ViewData["Title"] ="Movies - " @Model.Region;
But get an error "IEnumerable  does not contain a definition for 'Region'....."

This works fine in a typical 'Details view' where the model is simply....

```
@model MaltaMoviesMVCcore.Models.Movie and not ienumerable.
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a MovieModelClass:

```
public class MovieModel
{
public string Region {get; set;}
public IEnumerable<MaltaMoviesMVCcore.Models.Movie> Movies {get; set;}
}
```

and init it inside of your conroller

Change your model inside of the view :

```
@model MovieModel
```

After this you can use

```
ViewData["Title"] ="Movies - " @Model.Region
```

You can access your movies list using :

```
@Model.Movies

//for example
foreach(var movie in @Model.Movies)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sergey for your help.

That didn't quite work.

In the end I got the regionname ('MALTA') form the 'Context.Request.Path.Value' ('MOVIES/MALTA').
Initially I tried using Context.Request.Query["RegionName"] but this returned null
I know the preferred way is to get it from the model.

Final code...

```
// Get the last part of Request. Path '/MOVIES/MALTA'
        string path = Context.Request.Path.Value.ToString();
        string regionname = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```